# Angular $compile template for dynamic email

Tags: angularjs, email, compilation, interpolation

I am trying to load a html template with ng-repeats in it and then use the `$compile` service to compile it and use the compiled html in an email.

The problem.... Ok before asking let me set terminology...
binding placeholder: `{{customer.name}}`
binding value: `'john doe'`

Using `$interpolate` i get the actual binding values but does not work with ng-repeats.

Example:`var html = $interpolate('<p>{{customer.name}}</p>')($scope)`
Returns: `'<p>john doe</p>'`
Ng-repeats do not work

Using `$compile` i get the bindings placeholders ie `{{customer.name}}` but what I need is the binding value `'john doe'` .

Example: `var html = $compile('<p>{{customer.name}}</p>')($scope`)
Returns: `'<p>{{customer.name}}</p>'`

Once I append to a page I see the binding values. But this is for email not for a page plus it has ng-repeats that `$compile` can compile

How can I create a dynamic email template that after compiling it, it returns  html with binding values and not just the binding placeholders so I can send it as email?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using $compile is the right way to go. However, `$compile(template)($scope)` doesn't yield the interpolated HTML that you expect right away. It just links the compiled template to a scope to be interpolated during the next `$digest`. To get the desired HTML, you need to wait for that interpolation to happen, like so:

```
var factory = angular.element('<div></div>');
factory.html('<ul ng-repeat="...">...</ul>');
$compile(factory)($scope);

// get the interpolated HTML asynchronously after the interpolation happens
$timeout(function () {
  html = factory.html();
  // ... do whatever you need with the interpolated HTML
});
```

(working CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxEfr?editors=101)

Comment: Thank you very much! $timeout was the key!