# create mail template with $compile in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, templates, compilation

I have a large html file with some css in it. This html forms the body for follow up email after filling in a form. The way it is implemented now, is by string concatenation, which I don't like. The new html email body is also larger. I figured I could do it using angulars $compile function but I cant get it to work correctly.

This is the [link to the plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/PIJTlTI6jyDnegrWoCdi). I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358853/angular-compile-template-for-dynamic-email) (which is the current state of the plunk) and also [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835144/how-to-send-html-email-with-agularjs).

The completed and 'interpolated' (whatever that means) string is a parameter for a REST call to the server, which will send the actual email. So I would like to keep the creation of the template in a function which the user can execute with for example a ng-click. This is what I mean:

```
composer.$inject = ["$http", "$compile", "$scope", "$templateRequest", "$timeout"];
         function composer($http, $compile, $scope, $templateRequest, $timeout) {

           $scope.person = {
             firstname:"jonny",
             lastname:"Bravo"
           };

           compose();


          function compose() {
            $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html){
              var template = angular.element(html);
              console.log(template);
              $compile(template)($scope);
              console.log(template);

              $timeout(function() {
                $scope.htmlitem = template.html();
              });

           });
          }
```

I really wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to append `complied result` to `document` before get `template.html()`.**

**Fixed [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3AMlRZdZYTVE27K3gOic?p=preview)**.

With a little trick by using `directive` to complie template and provide the value back to your controller. Hope it works, any problems let me know plz.

```
.directive("htmlBuilder", htmlBuilder);

htmlBuilder.$inject = ["$http", "$compile", "$templateRequest", "$timeout"];

  function htmlBuilder($http, $compile, $templateRequest, $timeout) {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngController',
      link: function(scope, $elements, attrs, ctrl) {

        $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html) {
          var template = angular.element(html);
          $compile(template)(scope);

          //Apend to document before get innerHTML
          $elements.append(template);

          $timeout(function() {
            var res = $elements.html();
            ctrl.setResult(res);
          });
        });
      }
    }


  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have another problem: changes on the model do not reflect in the compiled html. I should have better explained that in my original question. I have updated the plunker to better reflect this. However, your answer does answer my question (and I really had no idea i should have append the template ) so its only  fair to give you credit for it. Thanks!

Comment: Check [fixed plunder demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZfRKlyftC3mPuMSrtxVO?p=preview).

Comment: @ocket-san, you are welcome, and fix watching and reflect in the compiled html. As using an **isolated scope** of directive, you can access controller's `$scope` by `scope.$parent`.

Comment: you are my hero! If I could, I would accept again :-). I also see I made some stupid mistakes... really thanks for the quick response and answer!